# c# .NET isn't rendering russian characters

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm using regex to match a string of unicode and store it in a string. For example:

NOTE: The following content must be read from an outside text file or else visual studio will automagically render it into russian.

```
"Name": "\u0412\u0438\u043d\u043d\u0438\u0446\u0430, \u0443\u043b. \u041a\u0438\u0435\u0432\u0441\u043a\u0430\u044f, 14-\u0431",
```

I'm using the pattern:

```
"\"Name\":\\s*\"(?<match>[^\"]+)\""
```

However, when I store the match in a string, the string is saved as:

```
match = "\\u0412\\u0438\\u043d\\u043d\\u0438\\u0446\\u0430, \\u0443\\u043b. \\u041a\\u0438\\u0435\\u0432\\u0441\\u043a\\u0430\\u044f, 14-\\u0431"
```

.NET is storing the string with an extra "\"

I tried using:

```
match = match.replace(@"\\", @"\")
```

but .NET doesn't recognize @"\\" as existing because it is looking at the  'visualizer version'.

How can I store my unicode without c# adding an extra '\'?

EDIT:
Another point:

```
// this works!
string russianCharacters = "\u041b\u044c\u0432\u043e\u0432, \u0414\u043e\u043b\u0438\u043d\u0430, \u0432\u0443\u043b. \u0427\u043e\u0440\u043d\u043e\u0432\u043e\u043b\u0430, 18");
```

This renders correctly in the visualizer as russian characters. But when I store characters from a regex match FROM AN OUTSIDE TEXT FILE, it is stored as an excaped sequence.

How can I render my string as russian characters instead of an escaped sequence of unicode?

Comment: Um, no. .NET does no such thing. Perhaps you're confused because that's how the debugger *shows* .NET strings? Try saving the string to a plain text file instead, and you'll see how it *actually* looks (use `Encoding.Unicode` to be sure). The `\\` only exists in the "visualizer", that's why you can't replace it, not vice versa. .NET isn't looking at the "visualizer" version, you are.

Comment: No, **you** are looking at the visualizer version. There are no double backslashes. Also, what are you trying to accomplish by storing strings like this?

Comment: HTMLDecode works on string which were previously encoded using HTMLEncode. Since your string is not encoded so there is no way for .net to decode. see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The only thing adding an extra backslash is the debugger, and only for display purposes. But there does appear to be a legitimate question in here, just with a wrong initial analysis. Where is your data coming from? Does it have Unicode characters or escape sequences?

Comment: Please do not edit a question to add more questions. If you have a new question (in this case about Russian characters) then ask a new question. If you think it relevant include a link to the old question in the new one.

Comment: BTW, did you try `Regex.Unescape(myString)`? See [this IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/LQhMw1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you!! That did it! If you want to post a formal answer I can give you the bounty. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you read the string from a text file that actually contains literal Unicode points, not actual Unicode symbols. That is, your C# variable looks like:

```
var match = "\\u0412\\u0438\\u043d\\u043d\\u0438\\u0446\\u0430, \\u0443\\u043b. \\u041a\\u0438\\u0435\\u0432\\u0441\\u043a\\u0430\\u044f, 14-\\u0431"
```

or

```
var match = @"\u0412\u0438\u043d\u043d\u0438\u0446\u0430, \u0443\u043b. \u041a\u0438\u0435\u0432\u0441\u043a\u0430\u044f, 14-\u0431"
```

In this case, to get the actual  Unicode string, you need to use [**`Regex.Unescape`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.unescape(v=vs.100).aspx):

> Converts any escaped characters in the input string.

[C# demo](http://ideone.com/LQhMw1):

```
var s = "\\u0412\\u0438\\u043d\\u043d\\u0438\\u0446\\u0430, \\u0443\\u043b. \\u041a\\u0438\\u0435\\u0432\\u0441\\u043a\\u0430\\u044f, 14-\\u0431";
Console.WriteLine(s); 
// \u0412\u0438\u043d\u043d\u0438\u0446\u0430, \u0443\u043b. \u041a\u0438\u0435\u0432\u0441\u043a\u0430\u044f, 14-\u0431
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Unescape(s));
// Винница, ул. Киевская, 14-б
```

Comment: Briliant solution!

Answer (score 3):

The extra '\' is just an escape character. I'm guessing you are viewing the value in the debugger window in which case it is showing the extra '\' but the underlying value will not have the extra '\'. Try using the actual value and you will see this.

This code works as expected:

```
var myString = "\"Name\": \"\u0412\u0438\u043d\u043d\u0438\u0446\u0430, \u0443\u043b.\u041a\u0438\u0435\u0432\u0441\u043a\u0430\u044f, 14 - \u0431\",";
var pattern = "\"Name\":\\s*\"(?<match>[^\"]+)\"";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
MatchCollection matches = rgx.Matches(myString);

if (matches.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
        var ma = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(match.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I correctly render the unicode as russian characters? The visualizer is showing \u0412\u0438\u043d\u043d\u0438\u0446\u0430, \u0443\u043b. \u041a\u0438\u0435\u0432\u0441\u043a\u0430\u044f, 14-\u0431 which is correct, but I want the string to be actually rendered russian characters

Comment: Still not working for me. In your example myString is automagically rendered into russian characters. But it you match your regex to an outside text file, it will save as an escaped unicode sequence and not actual russian chars