# Convert string with encoded UTF8 symbol into cyrillic symbol c#

Tags: c#, utf-8, httpwebrequest

From request http://ua-zip.net/script/suggest.php?prefix=61105&type=index I receive an answer like this:

> "\"1
>   \u0410\u0441\u043a\u043e\u043b\u044c\u0434\u0456\u0432\u0441\u044c\u043a\u0438\u0439".

For request I'm using:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(FullRequestString);
    request.Method = "GET";
```

I receive response by the construction:

```
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
 {
  using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
   {
   string line = "";
   while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
```

How can I transform the character like \u043b into cyrillic symbol

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183907/how-do-i-convert-unicode-escape-sequences-to-unicode-characters-in-a-net-string

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36210284/8840033

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use HTML. Try replacing all the `\u` with `&#x` like `\u0410` will become `&#x0410;`. Dont forget the semicolon at the end. then just do this.

```
string cyrillicString = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(your_string_with_replaced_characters);
```

The resulting string will contain cyrillic characters

**Note :** `&#x` is used if the numbers are Hexadecimal. For decimal just use `&#`.

Comment: Thank's, it works